# Store relatively large text in session or db before user signs up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to create a page flow that allows the use to use the service before signing up, so the data that is created up until then must be stored in state.

My options, as I see so far are

1. Session in memory
2. Cookies
3. Store data directly to db as it comes in.

In this case the text/string that are generated during use can be up to 100k in size. With scalability in mind, which approach would be best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store 100k of data in session variables or cookies.  There are downsides in terms of performance and security

You should store them in the database as it comes in, either in a staging area or a form that is flagged as initial.

Comment: Hi Michael. Yes, this is indeed the initial route I went. Just get the data out of memory asap and commit to the db. Just wanted to confirm

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that I think the cookie store limit is 4kb, so it is not even possible to store 100kb.  Have you looked into HTML5 local storage?  I think the limit there on browsers is 2.5-5+ MB giving you a lot more space.

Comment: Good point. For now I am staying away from HTML5 unless its an absolute requirement... too much IE madness involved. ;) But thanks.